# Git Files being Modified after Rebase, Fetch and Reset

Tags: git, fetch, reset, rebase

My co-worker rebased my branch with master and did some work and pushed to the remote. In order to prevent the conflicts, after he pushed, I did a `fetch` and `reset --hard origin/<my branch>`

I continue my work and would like to add, commit and push for my changes, but some files not belong to me got modified. (I am sure I didn't touch those files)

When I do `git status` at my branch:

```
    $ git status
On branch my-branch
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/my-branch'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   1
    modified:   2
    modified:   3
    modified:   4
    deleted:    5
    deleted:    6
    modified:   7
    modified:   8
    modified:   9

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I only changed 1 and 2, from 3 to 9 are the files I didn't touch.

My questions are:

1, Why the files I didn't touch got modified?

2, If I just do `git add` on file 1 and 2, will there be any future impact? (like impact on merge, pull)

Comment: You probably won't be able to merge or pull if those modified/deleted files would be overwritten by the merge. It's likely that some software you're using is changing these files? Don't commit files that are generated

Comment: I actually don't want to add 3 to 9 into staging area as those are not my files..I am worrying when I merge to qa or production, will that be a problem? I don't think any software changing the files, I have no clue why they have been changed in my staging area. I did a reset --hard, I suspect that may causing remote tracking ref diff with my working tree..